# sort files recursively in a directory using lambda in python

Tags: python, sorting

I have files like /test/abd.txt, test/ghk.txt, test/zgh.txt, test/bhg.txt
I'm sorting using lambda but since reading as path the sort is not working. how to sort just by filename, tried few ways and not working:

```
path = '/test'
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt'))
#print(os.path.basename(files))
#print(Path('path').name)
#sorted_files = sorted(files, key=lambda tup: tup.split('.')[1].lower())
#print(sorted_files)
```

output should be abd.txt, bhg.txt, ghk.txt, zgh.txt

Comment: list index starts at `0`, so `split('.')[1]` is actually the `.txt` part (which is identical)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just wanted the file names themselves without the `path`:

```
sorted_files = sorted(os.path.basename(f) for f in files)
```

If you wanted it sorted by just the file name without extension:

```
sorted_files = sorted([os.path.basename(f) for f in files], key=lambda x: os.path.splitext(x)[0])
```

Though, with the same `path` and extension I don't understand the need for this.  The sort should work just by itself: `sorted(files)`

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted_files = sorted(files, key= lambda temp: temp[0:-4].lower())
```

Comment: @zhanymkanov do you know what `-4` as index means?

Comment: for  input x = ['dfreqsdfadsf.txt','abc.txt','asdfasdf.txt','z.txt','a.txt'] output is ['a.txt', 'abc.txt', 'asdfasdf.txt', 'dfreqsdfadsf.txt', 'z.txt']